# Dynamic width of image for specific container width only

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Image container div "imagebox" contains list item with images.

CSS:

```
   ul.imagebox {
    width =100%;
    min-height:1000px;
    margin:0
    }

    li.image{
    float:left;
}
```

html

```
<ul class="imagebox"> 
<li class="image"><a><img src ="Images/Image1.jpg"/></a></li>
<li class="image"><a><img src ="Images/Image1.jpg"/></a></li>
<li class="image"><a><img src ="Images/Image1.jpg"/></a></li>
<li class="image"><a><img src ="Images/Image1.jpg"/></a></li>
<li class="image"><a><img src ="Images/Image1.jpg"/></a></li>
<li class="image"><a><img src ="Images/Image1.jpg"/></a></li>
<li class="image"><a><img src ="Images/Image1.jpg"/></a></li>
<li class="image"><a><img src ="Images/Image1.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Actual image size in 400 px x 300 px. Now I want to set width and height for img src dynamically using jQuery so imagebox div contains 5 images/row only. I want to set it dynamically only for window width more than 1024. So even if window width is  1600 and window is resizes up to 1024, image width and height gets resize to maintain number of images per row.

jQuery

```
$(window).ready (function(){
var imagebox = $("ul#imagebox").width();
var image_width = (imagebox/5);
var image_height = (image_width * 0.75);

});
```

I got width and height required for `img src` using jQuery. guide me to set this for `img scr` for window width more than 1024 (initially document load or after on window resize). 
And below window width less than 1024 ( for responsive design) I want to have any number  of images per/row (may be 4 ,3 or 2) without any gaping.

So I want to achieve

1. Dynamic width and height parameter works only for window width more than 1024.
2. for window width less than 1024 image width and height using css3 media queries

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/BkLfK/1/

Comment: you can add width: 20% to images

Comment: with 20% I can get 5 images /row , but i want to set 5 images/row upto window width 1024 px only. below this width I want to set static width height for images using css3 for different screen widths

Comment: @Fags --> Thanks for helpful fiddle . But you have set static width and height so there is gaping remains . I want to occupy whole imagebox thats why I want to set dynamic width & height,so even after window resize there will be no gaping.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help. The code below will change `your_images` height and width if `window size is > 1024`, and runs on window resize as well as document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   changeSize();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    changeSize();
});

function changeSize() {
   var docw = $(document).width();

   var imagebox = $(".imagebox").width();
   var image_width = (imagebox / 5);
   var image_height = (image_width * 0.75);

   if(docw >= 1024){
     $("your_images").width(image_width);
     $("your_images").height(image_height);
   }
}
```

Comment: @galexy check my edit. The second bunch of codes will run everytime the window is resized. Check out the links I provided for more reading. And you need the proper selector if you want to use the code I provided.

Comment: Just make sure you use the proper selectors and your good to go. Leave a comment if your having problems.

Comment: @galexy I made some changes. change your code from `var imagebox = $("ul#imagebox").width();` to `var imagebox = $(".imagebox").width();` I edited my answer. BTW change your css `width =100%;` to `width:100%;`

Comment: I did it, your code works fine on window resize only. Just want to know how to set width height initially . initially I am getting images with original dimension (400 x 300) and  jquery width & height set only after resize.

Comment: @galexy did you include the first block of code also? because you need `both blocks` of code to work. The first block of code is during `page ready` the second block of code is during `page resize`. I tried both awhile ago and it worked for me.

Comment: @Josepine ! ohk thanks , i didn't added!  Is there any way to combine both block instead of setting same jquery variable twice ?

Comment: @galexy check SHORTER VERSION. Just add that and only that and your good to go. Don't forget to check my answer so that others will know that this has been answered.

Comment: Joe, looks like good work. I tidied your code up to the most compact & correct version. +1

Comment: Thanks Joe and josepine ! its works for . just my work  is to set static image width & height for different screen (for tablet and mobile).